# VS code background clipping?

Tags: visual-studio-code

High width window messes up with the theme, the IDE looses the background color. Only when not on full screen.

So this seems like an issue that only happens only when not in full screen and on high width.

My environment is a Macbook Pro 2020. Running MacOS Catalina.

My theme is: Tokyo Midnight Storm

Let me know if you need more info.

Does anybody know how to fix this?

edit: Resolution: 1440p

see here:
[image]

Comment: What resolution are you running in? I have noticed screen re-paint glitches when running at higher resolutions.

Comment: I'm running it at 1440, this might be it. Do you know if there's anything to do about it?

Answer (score 0):

After looking more into it on the vscode repo I found that the solution is to close VS code, go to your terminal and open vscode through there with the following flag:

`code --disable-gpu`

This is not a solution of course, it's a way to go around the problem. You could make an alias too I suppose.

Either way I hope this helps.